# how to use ng-option to set default value of select element

Tags: angularjs

I've seen the documentation of the Angular select directive here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select. 
I can't figure how to set the default value. This is confusing:

> select as label for value in array

Here is the object:

```
{
    "type": "select", 
    "name": "Service",
    "value": "Service 3", 
    "values": [ "Service 1", "Service 2", "Service 3", "Service 4"] 
}
```

The html (working):

```
<select><option ng-repeat="value in prop.values">{{value}}</option></select>
```

and then I'm trying to add an ng-option attribute inside the select element to set `prop.value` as the default option (not working).

```
ng-options="(prop.value) for v in prop.values"
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

So assuming that object is in your scope:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-model="prop.value" ng-options="v for v in prop.values">
  </select>
</div>
```

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.prop = {
    "type": "select", 
    "name": "Service",
    "value": "Service 3", 
    "values": [ "Service 1", "Service 2", "Service 3", "Service 4"] 
  };
}
```

Working Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/wTRXZYEPrZJRizEltQ2g

Comment: ok i got it! the `ng-option` is replacing the `<option ng-repeat="value in prop.values">{{value}}</option>` thanks again

Comment: There has got to be a simpler way to do this, I find this very complicated for a simple select default value in angular js

Comment: ng-option directive is somewhat complicated and confusing on its syntax. I think the flexibility to bind objects has made it a bit complicated. The way I try to remember this is that whenever I am using an object, I explicitly indicate what properties to use for the value/text attributes of the select control. For more information see this:  http://www.ozkary.com/2015/08/angularjs-ngoption-directive-simplified.html

Comment: if you want to build a select in the view without writing out the options and have one selected
`<select ng-model="limit" value="10" ng-options="v for v in [5,10,15,20,30,50]"></select>`

Comment: @james Kleeh ..here u are hardcoding the first option since u know them.But if we dont know the options and how can we display the first one by default?

Comment: @HVarma `values[0]` ?

Comment: Does anyone know how to add default value as "Select option" as a default value

Comment: could you please let me know why alert is not showing any value. and how will it show?
http://plnkr.co/edit/CtgKthXCOjxxtB78?preview

Answer (score 69):

The [angular documentation for select](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select)* does not answer this question explicitly, but it is there.  If you look at the `script.js`, you will see this:

```
function MyCntrl($scope) {
  $scope.colors = [
    {name:'black', shade:'dark'},
    {name:'white', shade:'light'},
    {name:'red', shade:'dark'},
    {name:'blue', shade:'dark'},
    {name:'yellow', shade:'light'}
  ];
  $scope.color = $scope.colors[2]; // Default the color to red
}
```

This is the html:

```
<select ng-model="color" ng-options="c.name for c in colors"></select>
```

This seems to be a more obvious way of defaulting a selected value on an `<select>` with `ng-options`.  Also it will work if you have different label/values.

`*` This is from Angular 1.2.7

Comment: This worked for me, I doubt this will come up again but I'm currently using AngularJS v1.2.27 in case anyone finds this and is wondering about compatibility.

Answer (score 44):

This answer is more usefull when you are bringing data from a DB, make modifications and then persist the changes.

```
 <select  ng-options="opt.id as opt.name for opt in users" ng-model="selectedUser"></select>
```

Check the example here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/HrT5vUMJOtP9esGngbIV

Comment: Finally a working answer here, upvoted!
Also with this solution you can have the undefined option worknig properly.

<option value="">Please select</option>

Comment: So glad this post exists, I've been searching a while for a solution and this one has resolved my issue.

Answer (score 23):

```
<select name='partyid' id="partyid" class='span3'>
<option value=''>Select Party</option>
<option ng-repeat="item in partyName" value="{{item._id}}" ng-selected="obj.partyname == item.partyname">{{item.partyname}}
</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Bad practice here... Have a look to the second yellow note : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select.

Comment: this is not gonna work, ex. when you try to edit the record, how will the record bind with the field ?

Answer (score 21):

If your array of objects are complex like:

```
$scope.friends = [{ name: John , uuid: 1234}, {name: Joe, uuid, 5678}];
```

And your current model was set to something like:

```
$scope.user.friend = {name:John, uuid: 1234};
```

It helped to use the `track by` function on uuid (or any unique field), as long as the ng-model="user.friend" also has a uuid:

```
<select ng-model="user.friend" 
ng-options="friend as friend.name for friend in friends track by friend.uuid"> 
</select>
```

Comment: This answer made my day! Also take a look at track by in this documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: This is the best answer!

Answer (score 10):

I struggled with this for a couple of hours, so I would like to add some clarifications for it, all the examples noted here, refers to cases where the data is loaded from the script itself, not something coming from a service or a database, so I would like to provide my experience for anyone having the same problem as I did.

Normally you save only the id of the desired option in your database, so... let's show it

*service.js*

```
myApp.factory('Models', function($http) {
var models = {};
models.allModels = function(options) {
    return $http.post(url_service, {options: options});
};

return models;
});
```

*controller.js*

```
myApp.controller('exampleController', function($scope, Models) {
$scope.mainObj={id_main: 1, id_model: 101};
$scope.selected_model = $scope.mainObj.id_model;
Models.allModels({}).success(function(data) {
    $scope.models = data; 
});
});
```

Finally the partial html *model.html*

```
Model: <select ng-model="selected_model" 
ng-options="model.id_model as model.name for model in models" ></select>
```

basically I wanted to point that piece "*model.id_model as model.name for model in models*" the "*model.id_model*" uses the id of the model for the value so that you can match with the "*mainObj.id_model*" which is also the "*selected_model*", this is just a plain value, also "*as model.name*" is the label for the repeater, finally "*model in models*" is just the regular cycle that we all know about.

Hope this helps somebody, and if it does, please vote up :D

Comment: you could just bind the select to `mainObj.id_model` directly (`ng-model="mainObj.id_model"`), rather than using a 'placeholder / plain value' variable `selected_model`

Comment: yes, indeed, I just wanted to show that it could be done with a value directly within the $scope, but thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Is it possible to bind to an object and not just an int? I cant get my nGoptions to set its selected item because it doesnt know how to bind my {id:24} to my [{id:23},{id:24},{id:25}].

Comment: you can always use $index to get the position, however, yes it is possible to bind to an object

Comment: You can also use ng-options="model.name for model in models track by model.id_model"

Answer (score 10):

```
<select id="itemDescFormId" name="itemDescFormId" size="1" ng-model="prop" ng-change="update()">
    <option value="">English(EN)</option>
    <option value="23">Corsican(CO)</option>
    <option value="43">French(FR)</option>
    <option value="16">German(GR)</option>
```

Just add option with empty value. It will work.

[DEMO Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XBpdLMP53RR2Aec46NEJ?p=preview)

Comment: It really works if you add something like `<option value="" disabled>Please Select</option>`

Answer (score 8):

An easier way to do it is to  use [data-ng-init](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInit) like this:

```
<select data-ng-init="somethingHere = options[0]" data-ng-model="somethingHere" data-ng-options="option.name for option in options"></select>
```

The main difference here is that you would need to include `data-ng-model`

Comment: As specified in the docs: The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

Comment: The way I posted, with ng-options is much easier and more concrete. Both ways work.

Answer (score 4):

The *ng-model* attribute sets the selected option and also allows you to pipe a filter like *orderBy:orderModel.value*

**`index.html`**

```
<select ng-model="orderModel" ng-options="option.name for option in orderOptions"></select>
```

**`controllers.js`**

```
$scope.orderOptions = [
    {"name":"Newest","value":"age"},
    {"name":"Alphabetical","value":"name"}
];

$scope.orderModel = $scope.orderOptions[0];
```

Comment: Trying this and I see `angular.js:117 TypeError: a.forEach is not a function`.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is running into the default value occasionally being not populated on the page in Chrome, IE 10/11, Firefox -- try adding this attribute to your input/select field checking for the populated variable in the HTML, like so:

```
<input data-ng-model="vm.x" data-ng-if="vm.x !== '' && vm.x !== undefined && vm.x !== null" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Really simple if you do not care about indexing your options with some numeric id.

1. Declare your $scope var - people array

   ```
    $scope.people= ["", "YOU", "ME"];
   ```
2. In the DOM of above scope, create object

   ```
    <select ng-model="hired" ng-options = "who for who in people"></select>
   ```
3. In your controller, you set your ng-model "hired".

   ```
    $scope.hired = "ME";
   ```

It's really easy!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add up, I did something like this.

```
 <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="itemSelect" ng-change="selectedTemplate(itemSelect)" autofocus>
        <option value="undefined" [selected]="itemSelect.Name == undefined" disabled="disabled">Select template...</option>
        <option ng-repeat="itemSelect in templateLists" value="{{itemSelect.ID}}">{{itemSelect.Name}}</option></select>
```