# how to set the ng-model from known ng-options and criteria

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the efficient way to preselect an option based on some filter? My elements are e.g.:

```
[ {"name":"CSS1-1","id":"ce5e6a4299c68f0407b277fed38b4c657f20cfe8"},
   . . .
  {"name":"CSS1-2","id":"00f75732b5760a5bb36842e1db950d243bec87db" ]
```

and I want the element with id= 00f75732b5760a5bb36842e1db950d243bec87db preselected. In html

```
 <select ng-model="currentCss"
   ng-options="item.name for item in csss" />
 </select>
```

Data filled in here:

```
$scope.getCsss = function () {
    $http.get('/csss')
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.csss = data;                 
                $scope.currentCss =  ? ? ? 
                // I can start looping and comparing, 
                //but there must be a better way               
        }). . .
```

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/17329495/1331430

Comment: It is a bit similar but not very much. OP in the other issue didn't know about ng-model. The answer suggests using ng-model and setting a value equal to one of the options, all strings. I want to do the same, but my options are not strings. With strings "a"=="a" is true, with objects ["a"] == ["a"] is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `track by` expression in your `ng-options`

```
<select ng-model="currentCss"
   ng-options="item.name for item in csss track by item.id" />
 </select>
```

Then you can set an object with that id to select the correct `ng-model` value:

```
$scope.getCsss = function () {
    $http.get('/csss')
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.csss = data;                 
            $scope.currentCss =  { id: data.currentId }; // not sure the format here            
        })
```

This is is an excerpt from [the docs:](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect)

> trackexpr: Used when working with an array of objects. The result of
>   this expression will be used to identify the objects in the array. The
>   trackexpr will most likely refer to the value variable (e.g.
>   value.propertyName).

Comment: Thhat's what I needed, thanks! Another useful sentence from the docs about the case track by item.id: Two objects are considered equivalent as long as their id property is same.