# ng-option send diction instead of a string

Tags: angularjs

Have a simple CRUD app. Use $resource.

object

```
{
    name: 'name',
    url: 'some.api.com/api/customer/12334723847892347qw89e798/'
}
```

Query get all objects,

`customersList = customersService.customerResource.query();`

and i make select from this list

```
<select name="" 
        ng-options="item.name for item in customersList track by item.url" 
        ng-model="project.customer">
</select>
```

but then i send from, have error, API need url string from selected object in project.customer.  But this select send object (dictionary).

How tell angular get only url porp?

Comment: `item.url as item.name for item in customersList`. Checkout the official documentation.

Comment: I try read, and use this code:

`item.url as item.name for item in controller.customersList track by item.url`

But, i have empty first element in DOM. 

`<option value="?" selected="selected" label=""></option>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329495/how-to-use-ng-option-to-set-default-value-of-select-element