# default selected option in ng-option

Tags: angularjs, selected, ng-options

[Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myNERV)

Need to have "Pune" as default selected option.

Here is the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329495). I need help in knowing how should I add attribute in my current data structure for selected option.

```
<div ng-app="storeLocater"  ng-controller="selectOptions">
  <select ng-model="cities" ng-options="store for (store,city) in stores"> 
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should change your data structure first

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20790515/2257553) was the answer. Thank you @New Dev

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the default value in your ng-model, which in your case is: `cities`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <select  ng-model="stores.Pune" ng-options="store for (store,city) in stores">
 </select>
```