# Angularjs using ng-options in select with a default value

Tags: angularjs, select

I would like to have the first element of my ng-options to be the default one:

```
<select data-ng-options='item.pk for item in items' data-ng-click='update()'></select>
```

(so this is different than having an `<option value=''>Default</option>` at the end of the select. I also would like update() to be called at the beginning (on the default option).
How can I achieve this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use ng-option to set default value of select element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329495/how-to-use-ng-option-to-set-default-value-of-select-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want to create a model for the select element:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.pk for item in items"
     ng-click="update()">
</select>
```

After that, in your controller, you want to set `selectedItem` to the first element in `items`, and call your `update` function:

`$scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[0];
$scope.update();`

Notice that you should define `update` before calling it.