# how to set the default value in select option in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-select2

```
<select id="marketSelect" ng-model="market" name="marketSelect" ng-change="update()" ng-options=" market.Label group by market.FYear for market in markets" class="form-control">  
</select>
```

The ID and label is stored in `$cookieStore`. I tried to set the default by using the code in the controller

```
$scope.market = $cookie.get('marketID');
```

But it does not work, I have tried `ng-init` also.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329495/how-to-use-ng-option-to-set-default-value-of-select-element

Answer (score 0):

get is returning a string, in your repeat statement i can see you are using object, instead of put-get can you try putObject-getObject ?

Answer (score 0):

What returns this line ?

```
      $cookie.get('marketID')
```

I think undefined, please check it.

Comment: I am getting the id for the selected value, but how can i get the "value"

Comment: "value" as in <option value="2">...</option> 
because this seems to work $scope.market = $scope.markets[2] but i cannot get the "value" of the option selected, i was able to get the id and the label text but how to get the value that is automatically assigned by angularjs

Answer (score 0):

You can solve by this way:

in controller:

```
$scope.markets = [
  {id:1,Label:'dd',FYear:2015},
  {id:2,Label:'pp',FYear:2014},
  {id:3,Label:'ss',FYear:2015},
  {id:4,Label:'kk',FYear:2014}
  ];

$scope.marketId = 1; // assume $cookie.get('marketID') get value = 1
```

In html:

```
<select id="marketSelect" ng-model="marketId" name="marketSelect" ng-change="update()"  ng-options="market.id as market.Label group by market.FYear for market in markets"  class="form-control">
```

[PLUNKER Demo Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/DzoyWEX686HHH7J2jq1M?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

**Through Function**

```
$scope.resetfunction= function() {
    $scope.countrylist= "";
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="selectBox" ng-model="countrylist" ng-options="list for list in filterCountry | orderBy:'toString()'"><option value="">Select</option></select>
```