# AngularJS: Select option is not selected by default

Tags: html, angularjs, cordova, select

Hi My current scenario is this: I want a default value too that should select.. Even if `select` is selected then also acceptable.. but it is blank at first..My code is this

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="tsk.value for tsk in task.dropdown_values track by tsk.id" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="checkvalue(task.id, selectedItem)" style="width:100%;margin-right:4%;">
</select>
```

I'ave used this code too but not working :(

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="tsk.value for tsk in task.dropdown_values track by tsk.id" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="checkvalue(task.id, selectedItem)" style="width:100%;margin-right:4%;">
    <option selected="selected">Select</option>
</select>
```

Checkout my code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your code like this :

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="tsk.value for tsk in task.dropdown_values track by tsk.id" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="checkvalue(task.id, selectedItem)" style="width:100%;margin-right:4%;">
    <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

here is the plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/fekkRctRM59ydI6zDnpY?p=preview

or you can use `ng-init` like as mentioned by [@zsong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18195305/4281154)

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="tsk.value for tsk in task.dropdown_values track by tsk.id" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-init="selectedItem='YourDefaultValue'" ng-change="checkvalue(task.id, selectedItem)" style="width:100%;margin-right:4%;">

    </select>
```

Or you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17329854/4281154)

Comment: thanks for your answer but both of these solutions are not working.. checkout my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lw3BZLZdEwbwLYGZu7et?p=preview)

Comment: @TechKid I have modified your plunker checkout http://plnkr.co/edit/fekkRctRM59ydI6zDnpY?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <select id="myselection" ng-init="selectedColors=3" ng-model="selectedColors">
        <option value="1">Red</option>
        <option value="2">Blue</option>
        <option value="3">Green</option>
    </select>
    <div>Selected Colors: {{selectedColors }}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Code for to displays by default Select options

```
<select ng-model="your model" ng-options="your options">
<option selected="selected" value="">Select options</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `ngModel` is `selectedItem`, so you have to set `selectedItem` to the value which you want as default in your controller:

```
//This sets the default value to the first item in your list
$scope.selectedItem = $scope.task.dropdownvalues[0].value
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not have an option tag if using an ng-option

utilize ng-model instead as below.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="tsk.value for tsk in task.dropdown_values track by tsk.id" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="checkvalue(task.id, selectedItem)" style="width:100%;margin-right:4%;">
```

in your controller

```
$scope.selectedItem = dropdown_values[0];
```

will resolve your issue.

Comment: Ops it is not working bro :( 
my because in my scenario I have array of 100 tasks. and in each task it has drop down value.. and when i initialize your suggested `$scope.selectedItem` in my controller it says `dropdown_values` is not defined..

Comment: it would be $scope.dropdown_values... Well can you please share a plunkr I would help you out with it.

Comment: Use ng-repeat instead of ng-option and it will by default select an option for you. As you are having select element inside and ng-repeat you cannot set ng-model because it is in loop and you are assigning ng-model to 2 input at the same time to different elements in loop.

Its better you can use ng-repeat I have **modified your plunkr** for the same, kindly check

Comment: Sir, I can't see the modification into my current plunker.  Please sure Did u save the changes ?

Comment: Did u made changes into my this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UtQZsb8rkTovFEsc7SRR?p=preview)?

Comment: `<select class="form-control" style="width:100%;margin-right:4%;">
          <option ng-value="tsk.id" ng-repeat="tsk in task.dropdown_values">{{tsk.value}}</option>
         </select>`

I am not able to save the changes as I do not have rights but above is the changed code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100375/discussion-between-tech-kid-and-wasim-mulla).

Answer (score 1):

Many times I have spend hours to find out the solution, <kbd>***believe me!***</kbd>

[ 1 ] `Select Option` with Numbers (Used in `Pagination`, Page Size Selection)

```
<select id="select_pagination_pages" ng-model="recordsInPage">
    <option value="10" selected>10</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="75">75</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="150">150</option>
    <option value="200">200</option>
    <option value="250">250</option>
</select>
```

Inside Controller, particular page init function, I have inserted 10 as String.

```
$scope.recordsInPage = "10".toString();
```

[ 2 ] Second `Select Option` is with simple yes or no selection.

```
<select class="rfc_text" id="select_flag" ng-model="rfc.flag">
    <option value="yes" selected>YES</option>
    <option value="no">NO</option>
</select>
```

Inside Controller initialized rfc.flag like -

```
$scope.rfc.flag = "yes";
```

[ 3 ] This third one `Select Option` is special and with tiny scenario, where model will only use last four option values, but the first one is selected by default.

```
<select id="select_timezone" ng-model="timezone_search">
    <option value="" selected>Search Entire</option>
    <option value="CountryCode">Country Code</option>
    <option value="CountryName">Country Name</option>
    <option value="TimeZone">Time Zone</option>
    <option value="TimeOffset">Time Offset</option>
</select>
```

Inside page controller init -

```
$scope.timezone_search = "";
```

I think three examples would be enough for peoples. :D