# How to use ng-options to set default value of select element reading from object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-options, angularjs-ng-model

I have the following data:

```
$scope.users = [
  {
    'id': 0,
    'name': 'Tom'
  },
  {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Jack'
  }
];
```

And I have a default object that is dynamically generated.

```
$scope.default = {
  'id': 1,
  'name': 'Jack'
}
```

I'm trying to set a default selected option in my ng-options based on `$scope.default` but because it's an object as opposed to a string, it doesn't seem to work.

```
<select ng-options="user.name for user in users" ng-model="default.name"></select>
```

I'm aware of this other question, but it doesn't work with objects.

[how to use ng-option to set default value of select element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329495/how-to-use-ng-option-to-set-default-value-of-select-element)

Comment: Use the ng-options syntax in one of the answers, then make a comparison in your controller between the default and the users and set the correct user index that matches the default. I think your issue is that you are trying to use the default object for the model instead of using it to identify the correct model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to use "as" and "track by" to define the label and the field to be compared:

```
<select ng-options="user as user.name for user in users track by user.id" ng-model="default"></select>
```

see the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/pereveyebu/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: If you use ng-model directly on default.name, your "id" doesn't will change after the select, and could be confuse the result (an object with id from one value, and name from other value)

Comment: I created a stripped down plnkr using your code, a much simpler example than I had before.  Are you willing to take another look at it?  Here is the new link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35142172/why-isnt-form-data-defined-in-this-re-usable-service

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

or try:

If it's dynamic ordering, then you could track by a custom field, user.orderNum or something you can alter. I haven't tested, but should get you in the right direction.

Comment: I've tried ng-init but I can't seem to make it work either. Can you share an example?

Answer (score 0):

By default, ngModel watches the model by reference, not value. Try

`<select ng-options="user.name for user in users track by user.name " ng-model="default.name"></select>`.

More [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)