# set default selected value in <option> in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to display by default a value from a json which is something like

```
[{"city":"SURAT"},{"city":"BARODA"},{"city":"AHMEDABAD"},{"city":"MUMBAI"}]
```

this is came from server. I am store this value in $scope.user_all_city and there is one city is provided to user which is i am stored in this

```
$scope.user_city = "surat";
```

now my select tag is something like this

```
<select ng-model="model.user_all_city" ng-options="rm.city for rm in user_all_city" ng-init="model.user_all_city=user_city">
```

it is display first value as a blank. it is return to me default city when i am print {{mode.user_all_city}} but it is didn't display as selected option in it.

please help me over here and how to call a function in when i am change the value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use ng-option to set default value of select element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329495/how-to-use-ng-option-to-set-default-value-of-select-element)

Comment: use ng-selected attribute

Comment: Please check my example.

Answer (score 1):

Try using ng-repeat instead of ng-options basically the ng-options is not that much descriptive  in angularjs.

```
  <select ng-model="cityName" required>
<option>Select city</option>
<option ng-selected="cityName==city" value="{{city}}" ng-repeat="city in cityList"></option>
</select>
```

here the required attribute will enusre that select city is highlighted in case of null value. and ng-selected will check if that expression is true and the only that object is selected.The value inseide the model=cityName play the role of selected value here.