# <select> with ng-model and static options (true/false)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple select element which I want to use to set a boolean value:

```
# JS; somewhere inside the controller
var vm = this;
vm.isAdmin = false;
return vm;

# HTML
<select ng-model="formCtrl.isAdmin">
    <option ng-value="true">Yes</option>
    <option ng-value="false">No</option>
</select>
```

Unfortunately, when loading the site, nothing is selected.
I know I could use ng-repeat, but I don't want to because it seems unpractical to me.

**UPDATE:**
While the possible duplicate has basically the same accepted answer (because it's the best way to achieve the desired behaviour), the question itself is different. I actually wanted to use hard-coded options, not ng-options/ng-repeat.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use ng-option to set default value of select element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329495/how-to-use-ng-option-to-set-default-value-of-select-element)

Comment: `<select ng-model="formCtrl.isAdmin" ng-options="opt.val as opt.name for opt in [{val:true,name:'Yes'},{val:false,name:'No'}]">` See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s0peo48d/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)?

```
<select ng-model="form.isAdmin" ng-options="o.value as o.name for o in options"></select>
```

`options` array in your controller:

```
$scope.options = [
    { 'name': 'Yes', 'value': true }, 
    { 'name': 'No', 'value': false }
];
```

### [Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dzm82h23/)

---

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', [function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.isAdmin = false;

  vm.adminOptions = [{
    val: true,
    name: 'Yes'
  }, {
    val: false,
    name: 'No'
  }];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as form">
    <select ng-model="form.isAdmin" ng-options="opt.val as opt.name for opt in form.adminOptions">
    </select>
    {{form.isAdmin}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, I need to use different terms for true and false (Yes/No). How can I achieve this?

Comment: @sboesch Updated my answer and JSFiddle.

Comment: I didn't want to use an object because it seemed too exaggerated for such a simple task, but I have to admit it's the cleanest solution. I'll accepts your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to basically use the following syntax for your option tag (use ng-selected):

```
<select ng-model="formCtrl.isAdmin">
    <option ng-value="true" ng-selected="formCtrl.isAdmin">Yes</option>
    <option ng-value="false" ng-selected="!formCtrl.isAdmin">No</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-options`:

```
<select ng-model="form.isAdmin" 
        ng-options="opt.val as opt.name for opt in [{val:true,name:'Yes'},{val:false,name:'No'}]">
</select>
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s0peo48d/2/)