# Angular ng-model value not set as default on page load

Tags: angularjs

My HTML looks like this

```
<select ng-options="possibleConflict.id as possibleConflict.value for possibleConflict in possibleConflicts" ng-model="key"></select>
```

and the controller looks like this

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.key = 2; // Note This value can change 
  $scope.possibleConflicts = [{
      id: '1',
      value: 'red'
    }, {
      id: '2',
      value: 'blue'
    }]
}
```

[**Here is a working Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/i4BRP7xfgevZHwx6wAmu?p=preview)

Why isn't "red" selected as default when the page loads ? and how can I get it to be set as default ?

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329495/how-to-use-ng-option-to-set-default-value-of-select-element) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194255/how-to-have-a-default-option-in-angular-js-select-box) thread, but couldn't find a solution

Answer (score 1):

Just set `$scope.key = "1";` It should do the trick. It has to be a string value since that is what you defined in your array.

Comment: Doesn't work, you can test it in the plunker example

Comment: I believe it does. Working plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/C2LdF3NSLPzT7ytT86Ip?p=preview

Comment: Ok I see it works, I dumbed down the code down to put in plunker to test, it seems the type does matter, I thought angular would automatically cast it to the correct type

Answer (score 0):

Try by just changing your `key` variable to:

```
$scope.key = $scope.possibleConflicts[1].id;
```

Or changing both template and `key` variable:

```
<select ng-options="possibleConflict  as possibleConflict.value for possibleConflict in possibleConflicts" ng-model="key"></select>
```

together with

```
$scope.key = $scope.possibleConflicts[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

you should set the default value as a string: '2'

```
$scope.def = '2';
```

and the 'blue' is selected.

Answer (score 0):

**Working demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.possibleConflicts = [{
      id: '1',
      value: 'red'
    }, {
      id: '2',
      value: 'blue'
    }];
    $scope.key = $scope.possibleConflicts[0].id; // Note This value can change
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-options="possibleConflict.id as possibleConflict.value for possibleConflict in possibleConflicts" ng-model="key"></select>
</div>
```