# angularjs select nth child in ng option

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I use this Jquery to select nth child

```
<select class="perf-select">
    <option selected>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
```

**jquery**

```
jQuery('.perf-select>option:eq(2)').prop('selected', true);
```

How i achive this in angularjs ng-option

```
<select class="perf-select" ng-model="viewProfileCtrl.graphsForm.institution"
                        ng-options="inst.institution.institution_id as inst.institution.name for inst in viewProfileCtrl.perfiosAnalysisData.institutions"
                        ng-change="viewProfileCtrl.setGraphInsti(viewProfileCtrl.graphsForm.institution)">
                        <option value=""  selected>Select a Bank </option>
                     </select>
```

Comment: init model in controller to select default value

Comment: How achive this i am new from Angularjs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use ng-option to set default value of select element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329495/how-to-use-ng-option-to-set-default-value-of-select-element)

Comment: Do you have to select the Nth child or just know the value for default?

Comment: I want to set nth child

Answer (score 0):

Please use *selectedOption*  For more information https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select and go to **Using select with ngOptions and setting a default value** section. I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Best way so far to do this is by `array.indexOf`

```
ng-options="countries.indexOf(country) as country.name for country in countries"
```

[Working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6YQ9fMe4l538nX77ctHp?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set nth child as default option in dropdown you have to set your ng-model as per your nth child in the controller like--

> $scope.graphsForm.institution=3;

Here "graphsForm.institution" is your dropdown model and "3" is the key (like your example "institution_id") of your nth child that you want to set as default.

You can check this for better understanding--

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="datCtrl">

        <select class="perf-select" ng-model="graphsForm.institution"
   ng-options="inst.institution_id as inst.name for inst in institutions"
   ng-change="setGraphInsti(graphsForm.institution)">
   <option value="">Select Option </option>
  </select>

    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('datCtrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.graphsForm={};
   $scope.graphsForm.institution=3;
            $scope.institutions=[{institution_id:1,name:"oxford"},{institution_id:2,name:"havard"},{institution_id:3,name:"cambrige"}];
        });
    </script>

    

</body>

</html>
```