# ng-model in select not working with ng-submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is the code:

HTML

```
<form ng-submit="fun()">
  <select ng-model="a" ng-options="table.id as table.name for table in tables></select>
  <input type="text" ng-model="b">hello</input>
  <input type="submit">Ok</input>
</form>
```

JS

```
$scope.tables = [{"id":1, "name":"x"},{"id":2, "name":"y"},{"id":3, "name":"z"}]; 
//This is dummy data, tables is actually coming from another custom API
$scope.fun = function(){
  console.log($scope.a);
  console.log($scope.b);
}
```

This is the output:

```
undefined
hello
```

When I checked the source code, the options getting appended to my select look like this:

```
<option label="x" value="undefined:undefined"></option>
```

How can I get the selected option in the controller on ng-submit?

Comment: provide tables data

Comment: you are not appending any options for select.

Comment: When you render the HTML, which options can you see in dropdown list?

Comment: I have added tables array. The options are correctly displayed in the select box.

Comment: you must set the default value for selec in your model .This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20790515/5532806

Comment: Inputs don't have closing tags. `</input>` is illegal HTML.

Comment: Can't reproduce problem. Works fine in this [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/eFjZlifoVT3FpXHWdXoK?p=preview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this....as you changed your data i updated with that

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.tables = [{"id":1, "name":"x"},{"id":2, "name":"y"},{"id":3, "name":"z"}];
 $scope.fun = function(){
  console.log($scope.a);
  console.log($scope.b);
}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <form ng-submit="fun()">
  <select ng-model="a" ng-options="table.id as table.name for table in tables"></select>
  <input type="text" ng-model="b">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: In the value field of your output options, it is showing:
<option label="x" value="number:1">x</option>

But my options look like this:
<option label="x" value="undefined:undefined">x</option>

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/GCn12F4FC5IF3jI3WDm6?p=preview check this plunker and compare with yours

Comment: Thanks, found the bug

Comment: It was in my object array format. It was something like `{"values":{"id":1.....`
I was missing the `values` key.

Answer (score 0):

since you are accessing `table.id` and `table.name` in the `ng-options` you need to change your array to object array like this

```
$scope.tables = [{"id":"1","name":"1"},{"id":"2","name":"2"},{"id":"3","name":"3"}];
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

$scope.tables = [{"id":"1","name":"1"},{"id":"2","name":"2"},{"id":"3","name":"3"}];
$scope.fun = function(){
  console.log($scope.a);
  console.log($scope.b);
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <form ng-submit="fun()">
  <select ng-model="a" ng-options="table.id as table.name for table in tables"></select>
  <input type="text" ng-model="b" />
  <input type="submit"/>Ok
</form>
</div>
```

If you don't want to change the array then simply change the `ng-options` to this

`ng-options="table as table for table in tables"`

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

$scope.tables = ["1","2","3"];
$scope.fun = function(){
  console.log($scope.a);
  console.log($scope.b);
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <form ng-submit="fun()">
  <select ng-model="a" ng-options="table as table for table in tables"></select>
  <input type="text" ng-model="b" />
  <input type="submit"/>Ok
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Changed the array, still it is printing undefined

Comment: @Piyush Shrivastava can you create plnkr