# How to select option in select list Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have select list that is reproduced by `ng-options`:

```
<select  class="form-control" ng-options="i.id as i.os_version for i in devices track by i.id"
ng-model="selected_version_os_to" ng-change="selectVersionTo(selected_version_os_to)">
</select>
```

It generates options as:

```
<option label="10.3" value="1">10.3</option>
```

How to select option where `value == 1` or any another number?

I tried in `select tag`:

```
ng-selected="i.id == 1"
```

Comment: selected_version_os_to = 1 doesn't work ?

Comment: Yes, it does no work

Comment: Are you using `ng-options` or `ng-repeat`? Your post says `ng-repeat` but your code shows `ng-options`. Also it will be better if add controller code

Comment: I use `ng-options`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use ng-option to set default value of select element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329495/how-to-use-ng-option-to-set-default-value-of-select-element)