# Pre-set option in select box with customized text in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ng-options

I want to pre set my select box by using whole object available in my array. the text will be customized by using object fields as shown in below image

[image: Pre select object]

this is what I have tried so far

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-model="employee" ng-options="item as (item.name+' - '+item.post) for item in employees">
<option value="">select</option>
</select>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.employees = [{name:"Mehtab",post:"SE"}, {name:"Punit", post:"PM"}, {name:"Ashutosh", post:"SSE"}];
    $scope.employee = {name:"Punit", post:"PM"};
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use ng-option to set default value of select element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329495/how-to-use-ng-option-to-set-default-value-of-select-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this you want:

html:

```
<select ng-model="employee.name" ng-options='item.name as (item.name + " - " + item.post) for item in employees'>
<option value="">select</option>
```

JS:

```
$scope.employees = [
      {name:"Mehtab",post:"SE"}, 
      {name:"Punit", post:"PM"}, 
      {name:"Ashutosh", post:"SSE"}
    ];
$scope.employee = {"name":"Punit","post":"PM"};
```

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rum25Lxz/